# SetFocus and KillFocus

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I have a `CMFCTabCtrl` in my dialog and my `CMFCTabCTrl` has two tabs.

The first tab has a `CComboBox` and the second tab also has a `CComboBox`.

Whatever item newly added in ComboBox in first tab will reflect in ComboBox in second tab. Similarly, whatever item newly added in ComboBox in second tab will reflect in ComboBox in first tab.

For this, I have all ComboBox items in a vector and in each dialog's `WM_SETFOCUS` event I am adding items to ComboBox.

When user typing something in ComboBox but then user selects another control or dialog/tab also I am adding that item to ComboBox. For that I am tracking `CBN_KILLFOCUS` in parent's dialog `OnCommand` and adding the item to ComboBox.

Now my problem is when user type something in ComboBox and clicking on second tab, the `SetFocus` of second tab is called first and then only OnCommand with  `CBN_KILLFOCUS()` message is getting called. So the second tab is not having newly added item by the first tab whereas the first tab is having that item.

How to make the ComboBox item available to the second tab before it is getting displayed.

Comment: [WM_KILLFOCUS is the wrong time to do field validation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040419-00/?p=39753). Not the same use case, but the underlying principles apply here as well. You are simply using the wrong messages to perform actions. But since you are asking about your solution (rather than the problem you are *really* trying to solve), it's hard to make a suggestion.

Comment: In addition to IInspectable's comment: read [this](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do necessary operation(whatever operation I am doing on killfocus) on AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB, I am able to achieve my requirement.